# Change permissions of users and groups?

Tags: permissions, users, ftp, suse, wordpress

How can I list all users and groups and change their permissions?

I try to update Wordpress but my FTP user **intranet_admin** has not enough permissions and is unable to create a directory.

> Update WordPress
>
> Download the update from
>   https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/en_US/wordpress-4.9.7.zip ...
>
> Unzip the updated version ...
>
> Directory could not be created.
>
> The installation was not successfull

**Edit**: I found out that I can list all users with "*cat /etc/passwd*".
I found this entry:

```
intranet_admin:x:1002:1000::/srv/www/htdocs/wp-intranet:/bin/bash
```

What do I have to change so that the user will have enough permissions for updating wordpress?

---

### OT: Wordpress Problem solved!

I executed from within the Wordpress root directory:

```
find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

and then:

```
chown -R wwwrun:ftp-users /path/to/my/wp-directory
```

This solved the problem and I was able to upgrade!

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission to create a particular directory is not tied to the user account as tightly as you seem to think it is.  That is, it's not part of the account's entry in `/etc/passwd`.

A user can create (or delete) a directory in another directory if that other directory is writable by the user or by a group that the user belongs to.  This would also permit the user to create/delete files in that directory.

Example:

```
$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  staff  512 May  4 16:29 .
```

Here, only the user `myself` can create and delete files and directories while everyone is able to *access* the directory and *list* the directory content (the `x` and `r` permissions).

```
$ ls -ld .
drwxrwxr-x  2 myself  staff  512 May  4 16:29 .
```

In this case, the `myself` user as well as all users in the group `staff` can create and delete files and directories in the current directory.